# Dygraph and Graph not rendering under shiny tabs

Tags: r, graph, shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to create a shiny app in r. However, when I am trying to plot the dygraph and the last graph under their relevant tabs, they are not coming up in the tabs panels like the map and the first graph. I cannot figure out why I have tried numerous things to get them to show. Thank you in advance.

UI code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinydashboard)
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)
library(countrycode)
library(rworldmap)


ncov <- structure(list(Date = c("2020-05-07", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-07", 
                                "2020-05-07", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-07"), Country = c("Vietnam", 
                                                                                       "West Bank and Gaza", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
                                ), Confirmed = c(288L, 375L, 6L, 25L, 153L, 34L), Recovered = c(233L, 
                                                                                                176L, 5L, 1L, 103L, 5L), Deaths = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = 20004:20009, class = "data.frame")




ui <- fluidPage(

  #being able to select the country and get an individual graph
  titlePanel("Corona Virus"),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(
        inputId = "Country",
        label = "Country",
        choices = ncov$Country
      ), 

    ),
    dashboardPage(skin = "purple", 
                  #title of the dashboard
                  dashboardHeader(title = "CoronaVirus"), 


                  dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                                   sidebarMenu(
                                     id = "sidebarmenu",
                                     menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main"),
                                     menuItem("Map", tabName = "Map"),
                                     menuItem("Other Diseases", tabName = "Other Diseases"),
                                     menuItem("Whole World", tabName = "Whole World")



                                     #dashboard body                                 
                                   )),
                  dashboardBody(

                    tags$head
                    (
                      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom3.css")
                    ),

                    #confirmed number of cases
                    bsPopover (id = "q1", title = "Confirmed",
                               trigger = "hover",
                               placement = "top",
                               options = list(container="body")),

                    #recovered number of cases
                    bsPopover (id = "q1", title = "Recovered",
                               trigger = "hover",
                               placement = "top",
                               options = list(container="body")),

                    #Dead number of cases
                    bsPopover (id = "q1", title = "Dead",
                               trigger = "hover",
                               placement = "top",
                               options = list(container="body")),

                    tabItems(

                      tabItem(tabName = "Main",
                              fluidRow(
                                infoBoxOutput("info1"), width=10,
                                infoBoxOutput("info2"), width=10,
                                infoBoxOutput("info3"), width=10),
                              #dygraph of the whole world

                              plotOutput("plot"),

                              mainPanel(

                              )),#end main Panel

                      tabItem(tabName = "Map",
                              plotOutput("map"),
                              mainPanel()),
                      tabItem(tabName = "Other Diseases",
                              plotOutput("plott"),
                              mainPanel()),
                      tabItem(tabName = "Whole World",
                              plotOutput("plott"),
                              mainPanel())
                    )#end tab Items



                  )#end dashboard body
    )#end dashboard
  )#end side bar layout``
)
```

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data <- ncov %>% dplyr::filter(Country == input$Country)
    ggplot(data, aes(y = Deaths, x = Confirmed)) + geom_point()
  })

  output$plott <- renderPlot({
    data <- ncov 
    ggplot(data, aes(y = Deaths, x = Confirmed)) + geom_point()
  })



  #info box 1
  output$info1 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("Confirmed",sum(ncov$Confirmed,na.rm = TRUE),
            fill = TRUE, color = "yellow", icon("arrow-up"))})

  #info box 2
  output$info2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("Recovered",sum(ncov$Recovered,na.rm = TRUE),
            fill = TRUE, color = "green", icon("arrow-up"))})

  #info box 3S
  output$info3 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("Dead",sum(ncov$Deaths,na.rm = TRUE),
            fill = TRUE, color = "red", icon("arrow-up"))})

  output$map <- renderPlot({
    #map

    ans <-ncov %>%
      filter(Date=="2020-05-06")%>%
      select("Confirmed")


    count<-countrycode(factor(ncov$Country), origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')
    # create data frame with iso3 country codes and number of visits
    countriesvisited <- data.frame(countries =count, conf = ans)



    # inspect data

    visitedMap <- joinCountryData2Map(countriesvisited, 
                                      joinCode = "ISO3",
                                      nameJoinColumn = "countries")

    # get map
    worldmap <- getMap(resolution = "coarse")
    # plot worldmap
    plot(worldmap, col = "lightgrey", 
         fill = T, border = "darkgray",
         xlim = c(-180, 180), ylim = c(-90, 90),
         bg = "aliceblue",
         asp = 1, wrap=c(-180,180))
    # def. map parameters, e.g. def. colors
    temp <-mapCountryData(visitedMap, 
                          nameColumnToPlot="Confirmed",
                          oceanCol = "azure2",
                          catMethod = "categorical",
                          missingCountryCol = gray(.8),
                          colourPalette = heat.colors(171),
                          addLegend = F,
                          mapTitle = "",
                          border = NA)

    do.call(addMapLegendBoxes, c(temp,
                                 x = "left",
                                 title = "Corona Cases for the previous day",
                                 horiz = FALSE,
                                 bg = "transparent",
                                 bty = "n"))

  })

}#end server

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it necessary for me to install all of those packages just to demonstrate your issue on my machine, or can you reduce the code by removing unnecessary stuff so it's easier for others to run?

Comment: @CJYetman I have edited the code to make it less as best I can, and removed some packages.

Comment: You need to use ‘renderDygraph’ in server and ‘dygraphOutout’ in the UI: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html

Comment: @bs93 hi, even with that in the code, the plots are still not shown on the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab does not like spaces in the tab name. As soon as I took the spaces out, it started to work.